# How to Reuse Fragments code with different values in android?

Tags: android, listview, android-fragments, android-listview

I have made two fragments. One is a list fragment and other is a details fragment.
List Fragment shows the list of exams and when you click on an item in that list, details fragment shows its details. 
I want to use this same layout for different values. For example I have made this for all Law entrance exams and now I need to make for different exams like management, engineering, etc. with the same layout (list+details) but with  different corresponding values.

How can I solve this?

Comment: from where you are fetching data of exams(law,management,engineering)?

Comment: @kishorJoshi i m adding it from string array only using array adapter

Comment: Change the value in Array Adapter with required values and set adapter.notifyDataSetChanged();